# unexpected token test case error using preact, Jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, preact

I'm using Preact, jest & enzyme for unit test case but I facing below issue when I'm running test cases.

> Test suite failed to run
>
> node_modules/**/components/dd/index.jsx:1
>   ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { h, Component } from 'preact';
>                                                                                                   ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>
> at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
>     at Object. (**/components/**/index.jsx:2:43)

I referred below repo for setup jest script:
https://github.com/developit/preact-boilerplate